# \n not breaking lines in Java

Tags: android

I use a **google api** to **generate a QR code** from some data. It should be represent a **VCARD format**.
I call [this](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=BEGIN%3aVCARD%5CnVERSION:2.1%5CnFN%3aAdam%20Varhegyi%5CnN%3aAdam;Varhegyi%5CnEMAIL%3aadamvarhegyi20@gmail.com%5CnTEL:0670578978%5CnINTERNET%3a;%5Cn%5CnORG%3aEz%20a%20cegem.kft%5CnEND%3aVCARD) url.

When i read the QR code, i nicely got back all the information i added to the link, except one little error.

The **line sperators not working**.

***I got back this in Java (Android):***

```
BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1\nFN:Adam Varhegyi\nN:Adam;Varhegyi\nEMAIL:somemai@address.com\nTEL:1234567\nINTERNET:;\n\nORG:Mycompanyname\nEND:VCARD
```

***Instead of this: (\n = linebreaks)***

```
BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1
FN:Adam Varhegyi
N:Adam;Varhegyi
EMAIL:somemai@address.com
TEL:1234567
INTERNET:;
ORG:Mycompanyname
END:VCARD
```

I tryed to work it arround with **using a Scanner** like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(myVCardStringInputFromQrCode);
sc.useDelimiter("\n");
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String str = sc.next();
    Log.i("VCARD LINE: ", str);
}
```

And this method **only gives back 1 line!** It is **also ignores the "\n" marks.**

**Edit:**

I also tried to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` , but no use.

**Edit part 2:**

```
if(myVCardStringInputFromQrCode.contains("\n")){
    Log.i("Found linebreak", "TRUE");
}
else{
    Log.i("Found linebreak", "FALSE");
}
```

**This code gives me back "FALSE"** - Java says it is not contains "\n" when i clearly see it is.

Anybody know whats happening here?

**Edit part 3:**

**The correct answer was deleted for some reason so i cannot mark it as "answer".
The solution was "\\n" instead of "\n" and it is working.**

Comment: The code is working fine for me - is the vCard returned as a `String` or?

Comment: I just tested to take your output as string and printed it, it worked? in what format you are getting this value of vcard?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: Tryed it also, forget to mention in post.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi when you edit your question, please mention label `Edit:` so that it will not be taken as your edited code

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` you are seeing is not an actual line break.  It is an escaped line break (a backslash, followed by an "n" character).

Try replacing all occurrences of this with an actual line break.  Note that you should use the `\r\n` newline sequence because this is the newline sequence that vCards are supposed to use according to the specs.

```
myVCardStringInputFromQrCode = myVCardStringInputFromQrCode.replace("\\n", "\r\n");
```

Remember to pass `\\n` into the first argument and not `\n`.  You need two backslashes in order to get a literal backslash.

Answer (score 0):

`\r\n` instead of `\n` always worked for me.

Comment: is there any reason to use \r before \n. I always used \n and it worked all the time.

Comment: I was trying to post "Use \r\n" but the answer was to short. It simply works when I use it e.g. in my strings.xml (and "\n" doesn't). But the word "should" in my answer is a little bit of an overstatement. I'll try to find some resources

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast what do you develop with? I have a feeling that it has something to do with the environemtn which compiles the app. I work in Eclipse on Windows and Windows needs carriage return "\r". Do you develop on Linux?